# Devexpress TabbedView Free Layout Mode saving layout

Tags: winforms, layout, devexpress, tabbed-view

I want to save layout from my `TabbedView` with a custom xml serializer/deserializer. From the manual https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11355
its clear: `There is no need to add, remove or modify docking containers manually. If you wish to arrange your documents and groups in code, use the DocumentGroup.DockTo method`. But how to use this method? Possible position of document may differ from document ordering.

[image]

So i decided to use `Docking containers`. After that i have restored layout, but there is a problem: no `splitters` between `DocumentGroups` where added.

Here is a code:

```
TabbedView view = ((TabbedView)documentManager.View);

DockingContainer node = LoadViewsDockingContainers(parentNode.SelectSingleNode("DockingContainer"), documentManager);
view.RootContainer.Nodes.Add(node);
view.RootContainer.Nodes.RemoveRange(view.RootContainer.Nodes.Take(view.RootContainer.Nodes.Count - 1).ToArray());
```

---

```
private DockingContainer LoadViewsDockingContainers(XmlNode dockingContainerNode, DocumentManager documentManager)
{
    // adding nodes recursive 
    dockingContainer.Nodes.Add(LoadViewsDockingContainers(parentNode, documentManager));
    ....
    // adding element - DocumentGroup
    dockingContainer.Element = LoadGroupDockingContainers(node, documentManager, toRemove);
    return dockingContainer;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Nikolay. Do you really need custom serialization? Have you experienced any issue with embedded SaveLayoutToXXX/RestoreLayoutToXXX methods? Have you tried to extend the embedded serialization mechanism with adding some custom properties at the documents level?

Comment: Yes, `SaveLayoutToXXX` returned layout data, but no data about custom controls inside `Documents`. What do you mean by extending the embedded serialization? Could you provide some code, please?